# Keyboard keys mapped wrongly when connected to Hyper-V Ubuntu 22.04.2 via RDP

Tags: keyboard, hyper-v

I have a Ubuntu 22.04.2 created on Hyper-V. When I connect to this VM from any other Windows machine on the network via mstsc (Windows RDP client), I find that some of the keys are mapped wrongly. E.g: If the Up arrow key is pressed it brings in screen capture application, Right Arrow activates "Super R" and Left Arrow activates "Alt R"

This issue is not there when I connect to the same VM directly via the Hyper-V Console.

If I run `Setxkbmap -query`, I get the following output.

```
<p>rules:      base
<br>model:      pc104
<br>layout:     us
</p>
<p>
```

Is there a way to fix the keyboard mapping for the RDP connections?